# SF4 Authentication working but token not saved (serialize never called)

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, serialization, yaml

I'm in trouble with authentication with symfony 4 on my first REST API.

The fact is my authentication succeed, and then my redirect URL is called, but the authentication token is lost during this redirection. I've also noticed that my serialize method is never called on my User Entity.

What I want is : When my Authentication is succeeded, then my profile page is called.
But with that code, all I get is a 302 redirection from profile, means that my authentication works, but the token was lost (if it exist, never seen it)

My only hints are :

- Serialize method in User never called (is this important ?) EDIT : no because i need to be stateless, so remove those methods.
- My Authentication works because if I make a mistake in credential I got a correct error.

Here is the code :

My Provider

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Api\Auth\Provider;

use App\Api\User\Entity\User;
use App\Api\User\Repository\UserRepository;
use App\Domain\User\ValueObject\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;

class AuthProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \App\Api\User\Repository\UserRepository
     */
    private $userRepository;

    /**
     * AuthProvider constructor.
     * @param \App\Api\User\Repository\UserRepository $repository
     */
    public function __construct(UserRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $repository;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $email
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function loadUserByUsername($email)
    {
        try {
            $user = $this->userRepository->getUser($email);
        } catch (UnsupportedUserException $e) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException('User not found', 1001, $e);
        }

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface | User $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getEmail());
    }

    /**
     * Qualify the supported class for this provider
     * @param string $class
     * @return string
     */
    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        if (!$class instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                sprintf('Entity given is not supported, expected User got %s', $class),
                1000
            );
        }

        return $class;
    }
}
```

My Guard :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Api\Auth\Guard;

use App\Api\User\Repository\UserRepository;
use App\Domain\User\Exception\InvalidCredentialsException;
use App\Domain\User\ValueObject\Credentials;
use App\Domain\User\ValueObject\Email;
use App\Domain\User\ValueObject\HashedPassword;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;

/**
 * Allow the authentication by giving credential, when login process achieved and valid, profile page show up
 * Class LoginAuthenticator
 * @package App\Api\Auth\Guard
 */
final class LoginAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    const LOGIN = 'login';
    const SUCCESS_REDIRECT = 'profile';

    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * @var \App\Api\User\Repository\UserRepository
     */
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router, UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->repository = $userRepository;
    }

    /**
     * This method will pass the returning array to getUser and getCredential methods automatically
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->get('password')
        ];
    }

    /**
     * In the case or the Guard and the Authenticator is the same, this method is called just after getCredentials
     * @param mixed $credentials
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface $userProvider
     * @return null|\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface|void
     */
    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider): UserInterface
    {
        try {
            $email = $credentials['email'];
            $mail = Email::fromString($email);
            $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($mail->toString());

            if ($user instanceof UserInterface) {
                $this->checkCredentials($credentials, $user);
            }

        } catch (InvalidCredentialsException $exception) {
            throw new AuthenticationException();
        }

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * The ùail has been found, because a user has been identified, we take the has password we have to compare
     * @param mixed $credentials
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface $user
     * @return bool
     */
    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        $mail = Email::fromString($credentials['email']);
        $userCredentials = new Credentials($mail, HashedPassword::fromHash($user->getPassword()));

        // Plain password compared
        $match = $userCredentials->password->match($credentials['password']);

        if (!$match) {
            throw new InvalidCredentialsException();
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Called when authentication executed and was successful!
     *
     * This should return the Response sent back to the user, like a
     * RedirectResponse to the last page they visited.
     *
     * If you return null, the current request will continue, and the user
     * will be authenticated. This makes sense, for example, with an API.
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface $token
     * @param string $providerKey
     *
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate(self::SUCCESS_REDIRECT));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(): string
    {
        return $this->router->generate(self::LOGIN);
    }

    /**
     * Does the authenticator support the given Request?
     *
     * If this returns false, the authenticator will be skipped.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->getPathInfo() === $this->router->generate(self::LOGIN) && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }
}
```

My Security.yml

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        users:
            id: 'App\Api\Auth\Provider\AuthProvider'
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: users
            guard:
              entry_point: 'App\User\Auth\Guard\LoginAuthenticator'
              authenticators:
                - 'App\Api\Auth\Guard\LoginAuthenticator'
            form_login:
              login_path: /sign-in
              check_path: sign-in
            logout:
              path: /logout
              target: /
        api:
            pattern: ^/(/user/*|/api|)
            stateless: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - 'App\Api\Auth\Guard\LoginAuthenticator'


    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api, roles: USER }
        - { path: ^/user/*, roles: USER }
- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

My User entity

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Api\User\Entity;

use App\Domain\User\Repository\Interfaces\CRUDInterface;
use App\Shared\Entity\Traits\CreatedTrait;
use App\Shared\Entity\Traits\DeletedTrait;
use App\Shared\Entity\Traits\EntityNSTrait;
use App\Shared\Entity\Traits\IdTrait;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Api\User\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, CRUDInterface, \Serializable, EncoderAwareInterface
{
    use IdTrait;
    use CreatedTrait;
    use DeletedTrait;
    use EntityNSTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=false, nullable=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=254, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $email
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
        // see section on salt below
        return null;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('USER');
    }

    /**
     * From UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // Never used ?‡
    }
    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        var_dump('need it'); // never called
        return serialize([
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->email,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ]);
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->email,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
            ) = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $password
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the name of the encoder used to encode the password.
     *
     * If the method returns null, the standard way to retrieve the encoder
     * will be used instead.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEncoderName()
    {
        return 'bcrypt';
    }
}
```

It's my really first project on SF4, it's maybe a dumb mistake but can't find it.

EDIT : I tried to pass in security config the attribute stateless to false, my serialize method were called but then I have an access denied error on profile page.

I need to stay "stateless" but it may help you to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stateless firewall will never store the token in the session, so you have to pass the credentials for every request you make to the API.

Currently your guard class returns a redirect, so your authentication is lost due to symfony not storing the token for stateless firewalls. To solve this, you should return `null` in the method `onAuthenticationSuccess` instead of doing a redirect. This also means, that you should create a separate guard class for the API firewall.

You can also find a good guard example for APIs in the symfony docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html#step-1-create-the-authenticator-class

## Edit:

I slightly misunderstood what you are trying to achieve. So it seems that you want to have a pure REST application with symfony and authenticate the user once where you then get back a token which can be used for future requests.

Some time ago I had the same issue and I stumbled over a very good bundle called [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle). This bundle gives you the necessary feature you need out of the box.

If you install it by following the [Getting started](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/83cdd4f933729c2642c6aba3af9484f13f5fac40/Resources/doc/index.md) documentation, you should have the basics for this.

Your configuration should then look something like this:

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        users:
            id: 'App\Api\Auth\Provider\AuthProvider'
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/sign-in
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            form_login:
                check_path:               /api/login_check
                username_parameter: email
                password_parameter: password
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false
        api:
            pattern: ^/(/user/*|/api|)
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator


    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api, roles: USER }
        - { path: ^/user/*, roles: USER }
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

But don't forget to add the  login_check route to your `routes.yml`

```
api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check
```

If everything is setup correctly, you should now be able to retrieve a new token with the following request:

```sh
curl -X POST http://localhost/api/login_check -d _username=yourUsername -d _password=yourPassword
```

The token you received with this call should then be used for all future request to the API. You can pass it via the `Authorization` header

```sh
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $YOUR_TOKEN" http://localhost/api/some-protected-route`
```

If you want to pass it differently (e.g. via query param) you have to change the configuration of this bundle:

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    token_extractors:
        query_parameter:
            enabled: true
            name: auth
```

Now you could use `https://localhost/api/some-protecte-route?auth=$YOUR_TOKEN` instead.

For more information about this, take a look at the [configuration reference](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/7bfe96e2283e671c948c8045ce9d1d1a43644515/Resources/doc/1-configuration-reference.md) of this bundle

I hope this helps a little bit to get you started with.

Comment: what look like my security file after this new guard ? I need only one login form and then depends on their roles they can access many resources.

Comment: from your edit : what if my username is an email ? plus my form_login use two variables email / password and not _username/_password does this change anything from your answer ?

Comment: You can easily adjust the username/password parameters via config (already edited it into the answer). The fact that symfony uses the term `username` but you pass an email is already handled in your user provider, so this is just a naming issue.